# Sharing Global variable in a dll linked to two exe's

Tags: c++, windows

`exe1` and `exe2` are statically linked to a `test.dll`.

```
//test.dll
MyComplexObject obj;
void func()
{
   //initialize obj
}
void update()
{
   //update obj
}
// other functions that use obj


//exe1
func();

//exe2
update();
```

The problem is `exe2` will have a separate copy of `obj` so `update()` won't actually be updating the `obj` initialized by `exe1`. I want to keep the update portion in `testdll` itself and don't want to export `obj`.

Note: `exe1` is a windows service that will keep on running and `exe2` is a standalone application that can launched and closed multiple times.

Is it possible to update `obj` from `exe2`?

EDIT: I got to know that using `data_seg` is no longer supported on windows so it is not possible to share data across sessions.

My problem boils down to sharing of variable in a dll across different dll instances(loaded by an exe). Is inter process communication like boost.interprocess only reliable way or is there something similar and something that does not involve `boost`?

Comment: I'd suggest you look into shared memory.

Comment: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/interprocess.html

Answer (score 0):

If using visual c++ you can place the variable in a shared memory section by doing the following.

First, in the header declare the variable as normal for something exported from a DLL:

```
MYDLL_API int MyDllVariable;
```

In the source file when defining the variable:

```
#pragma section("shared_data", read, write, shared)
#pragma data_seg("shared_data")
__declspec(dllexport) int MyDllVariable;
```